# Cómo usar API REST Y PHP

Tags: php, api, rest

Buenas soy muy nuevo en esto de las APIs y tengo que traerme ciertos datos de una web via php usando API REST, mi duda esque hasta el momento no he conseguido nada , porque me bajé un repo desde github cuyo example.php muestra una página vacía sin datos, ni siquiera un xml o json que muestre nada, mi pregunta es alguien sabe más o menos como funcionan y podría ponerme un ejemplo básico para yo añadirlo y poder más o menos manejarme? gracias saldos

Uso la api de redmine.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Lamentablemente tu pregunta no se adapta al formato del sitio. Se requiere un problema concreto basado en código concreto. Aquí no podemos hacer las cosas por ti. Recomiendo que leas el tutorial de James en [hermosaprogramacion.com](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/10/servicio-web-restful-android-php-mysql-json/). Es cierto que está escrito incluyendo cosas de Android, pero a partir de aquí: **Planificación Del Servicio Web RESTful** te explica con claridad meridiana cómo crear tu propio servicio REST, y además de forma ordenada usando `MVC`. Está en español.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para consumir una `API` necesitas la `url`de la página web de la que quieras obtener los resultados. Estos, se devolveran en formato `JSON`o `XML`.

Puedes obtener estos datos de dos formas difernetes en PHP:

1) Usando `file_get_contents()`.

```
$datos = json_decode( file_get_contents('https://api.com/users/2333/'), true );
print_r($datos);
```

2) Usando `CURL`.

```
$ch = curl_init(); // Inicio el CURL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.com/users/2333/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$res = curl_exec($ch); // Respuesta
curl_close($ch); // Cierro el CURL
```

Comment: Podrías pasarme un pastebin o algo con el código de ejemplo completo para poder probarlo, uno aunque sea simplón, solo para ver coómo funciona, esque ando muy perdido con esto